# $http factory only working on first controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

I have a factory that is getting data and returning it to the controller. It works on the first controller, but returns nothing on the second. I was under the impression that I could pass this around to all the controllers. For a minute, I was thinking that maybe it could only be instantiated one time, so I created another factory with the same steps. Still same result. It returned an empty array in the second controller

```js
//Factory

angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('classData', function($http){

      return {

        getClassData : function() {

          var studentData = [ ];

          $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'theUrl'
          }).success(function(data){

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
              studentData.push(data[i]);

          }).error(function(){
            alert("error", error);
          });

          return studentData;

        }
      };
    });


//Controller 1:

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('studentListCtrl', function($scope, classData, statService) { //this controller is just view logic

    $scope.sortType     = 'attendanceYtd';
    $scope.searchStudent   = '';
    $scope.students = classData.getClassData(); //returns all   data
 
//Controller 2: 

angular.module('attendanceApp')
  .controller('studentHistoryCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, classData) {
    //get all  data
    $scope.students = classData.getClassData();
    console.log($scope.students); //returning an empty array
```

Comment: I am surprised that it worked at all, as it should not. Clearly you do not understand what asynchronous code is. success and error callbacks can be called event minutes later and you are returning result right away. It should not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return your promise, otherwise your object is returned before the execution of the promise.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('classData', function($http){

      return {

        getClassData : function() {

          var studentData = [ ];

          return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'theUrl'
          }).then(function(data){
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
              studentData.push(data[i]);
            return studentData;
          }, function(){
            alert("error", error);
          });


        }
      };
    });
```

and then, in your controller, use your promise :

```
classData.getClassData().then(function(results){
    $scope.students = result;
});
```

Comment: Thank You! Just tweaked my approach and it worked. Many thanks.